# Showing sort simulation

Tags: c++, sorting, bubble-sort

I'm trying to show the simulation of this bubble sort and I used a function swapper that has reference values but when I try to print it after the swap it also prints out the memory address. How can I fix this?

```
void swapper(int &a, int &b) {
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;

  return;
}

int main(){

//Bubble sort

int arr[] = {-2, 45, 0, 11, -9};
int n = 5;


for(int step = 0; step < n-1; step++) {

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
       swapper(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
  }

  for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
      cout << arr[x] << " ";

  cout << endl;

}
```

Comment: 1) you are missing one `}` at the end of your example. 2) [Can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/EMkUog).

Comment: UB in your code: reading `arr[i + 1]` for `i == n - 1` reads out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Fixing the bugs

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapper(int &a, int &b) {
  int temp = a;
  a = b;
  b = temp;

  return;
}

int main(){

    //Bubble sort

    int arr[] = {-2, 45, 0, 11, -9};
    int n = 5;


    for(int step = 0; step < n-1; step++) {

        for(int i = 0; i+1 < n; i++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
                swapper(arr[i], arr[i + 1]);
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < n; x++)
            cout << arr[x] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I added a missing `}` and changed the condition of the inner loop to `i+1 < n` to avoid array access out of bounds.

This is the output:

```
-2 0 11 -9 45 
-2 0 -9 11 45 
-2 -9 0 11 45 
-9 -2 0 11 45
```

### Aligning the output

You can make the output aligned more nicely by replacing

```
cout << arr[x] << " ";
```

with

```
cout << setw(2) << arr[x] << " ";
```

and writing

```
#include <iomanip>
```

at the top of your file. Then the output is

```
-2  0 11 -9 45 
-2  0 -9 11 45 
-2 -9  0 11 45 
-9 -2  0 11 45
```

Comment: Thanks for the help